# How can I custom sort the contentful response on the frontend of my angular app

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, contentful, ng-filter

I am using Contentful in my AngularJS app... I have a content type `team` which holds a list of team bios. http://uat.traverusglobal.com (bottom)

I have successfully gotten data from contentful using `angular-contentful`... Now I need to to sort the response by name or other contentful field. So that the admin has control over the order.

How can I sort the contentful response on the frontend of my angular app? Below is my attempt.

https://jsfiddle.net/k3jmq2gm/1/

```
    <div class="columns teams-list" contentful-entries="'content_type=staff'" ng-controller="teamContentful">
        <div ng-repeat="item in $contentfulEntries.items | orderBy:'item.fields.name'" class="column" data-flag="{{item.fields.flag}}" data-visible="{{item.fields.visible}}" ng-class='{active:$first}' data-tab="1" data-title="{{item.fields.title}}" data-name="{{item.fields.name}}">
            <!-- <h1>{{item[0].title}}</h1> -->
            <img src="{{ item.fields.image.fields.file.url }}" title="{{item.img}}">
            <p class="hide bio">{{item.fields.bio}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your `orderBy` should be `orderBy:'fields.name'` - https://jsfiddle.net/k3jmq2gm/2/

Comment: Man it is bitter sweet when the answer is that easy... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

as Und3rTow pointed out. `orderBy` should be `orderBy:'fields.name'`